# Passing a function as a parameter

Tags: functions

I am little confused how to pass a function.

Here is a function

```
f[x_] = x^2;
```

and here is my custom plot function (imagine it is something more complicated)

```
PlotFunc[func_] := Module[{fun = func}, Plot[fun[x], {x, 0, 4}]]
```

Now if I try

```
PlotFunc[f[x]]
```

nothing happens. Where am I wrong? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try `f[x_] = x^2; PlotFunc[func_] := Module[{fun = func}, Plot[fun/.x->y,{y,0,4}]]; PlotFunc[f[x]]` and look at `f[x_] := x^2; PlotFunc[func_] := Module[{fun = func},fun[3]]; PlotFunc[f[x]]` to perhaps get a hint why your original code was not giving you what you expected.

Comment: try `Plot[fun, {x, 0, 4}]` not `Plot[fun[x], {x, 0, 4}]` you already passed in `x^2`.

Comment: Or this: `f[x_] := x^2;
PlotFunc[func_] := Plot[func[x], {x, 0, 4}];
PlotFunc[f]`

Answer (score 4):

[image][image]

`PlotFunc[f[x]]` ends up being `f[x][x]` in your code. To get the picture you want, use `PlotFunc[f]`, as you have `func[x]` in your later code.

Comment: Thank you. What if f is a function of 2 variables, f[x,y], and I want to plot f[x,1]?

Comment: @Gordon PlotFunc[func_] := Module[{fun = func}, Plot[fun[x,1], {x, 0, 4}]]